# NSURLSession background session can run data tasks?

Tags: background, watchkit

The [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html) mentions gives one line

In Background sessions, Only upload and download tasks are supported (no data tasks)

but this [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Background_Task_Cancellation_reasons),

seems to indicate that background sessions can execute data tasks?

The behavior of a session is determined by the configuration object used to create it. Because there are three types of configuration objects, there are similarly three types of sessions: default sessions that behave much like NSURLConnection, ephemeral sessions that do not cache anything to disk, and download sessions that store the results in a file and continue transferring data even when your app is suspended, exits, or crashes.

Within those sessions, you can schedule three types of tasks: data tasks for retrieving data to memory, download tasks for downloading a file to disk, and upload tasks for uploading a file from disk and receiving the response as data in memory.

what is correct? will I be able to make a GET http request on an NSURL and then JSONSerialize the NSDATA received in the "Background"

Answer (score 1):

You can only run upload and download tasks in the background. Here's a quote taken directly from the [ULR Loading System](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html).

---

**Background Transfer Considerations**

The NSURLSession class supports background transfers while your app is suspended. Background transfers are provided only by sessions created using a background session configuration object (as returned by a call to backgroundSessionConfiguration:).

With background sessions, because the actual transfer is performed by a separate process and because restarting your app’s process is relatively expensive, a few features are unavailable, resulting in the following limitations:

- The session must provide a delegate for event delivery. (For uploads and downloads, the delegates behave the same as for in-process transfers.)
- Only HTTP and HTTPS protocols are supported (no custom protocols).
- > Only upload and download tasks are supported (no data tasks).
- Redirects are always followed.
- If the background transfer is initiated while the app is in the background, the configuration object’s discretionary property is treated as being true.

---

What you want to do instead is run your `GET` request as a download request and save the JSON data to a file. Once the download is completed, read the contents of the file into memory, and parse the `NSData` just like you would if it came from a data request.

Comment: I tested it on iOS 11.3 and a data task with a background session configuration that is started while the app is in the background end up with `Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-997 "Lost connection to background transfer service"` error. On the other hand, the same task gets successfully completed while the app is in the foreground. It proves @cnoon 's answer.